# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline have Heroku implications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Does the asset pipeline have implications for rails on heroku that I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, details can be found on Heroku's Rails 3.1 guide:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

Answer (score 0):

Take care of that during the "`rake asset:precompile`" phase there is NO environment. There is a config initialize_on_precompile which prevent Rails to connect to the db during this step. This is essential on Heroku.

BUT this config HAVE to go to config/application.rb and NOT to config/environments/production.rb. Keep in mind that there is no environment...